# How to make VARCHAR the preferred type for strings in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, casting

PostgreSQL have the "preferred types" for type categories.
For strings, the preferred type is TEXT, so if one calls

```
SELECT PG_TYPEOF('FOO' || 'BAR');
```

The result will be `TEXT`.

I've already tried to change the `pg_type` table like this:

```
UPDATE PG_CATALOG.PG_TYPE 
   SET TYPISPREFERRED = (UPPER(TYPNAME) = 'VARCHAR')
 WHERE TYPCATEGORY = 'S'
```

Now the `TYPISPREFERRED` column for the type TEXT is false and for VARCHAR is true, but `SELECT PG_TYPEOF('FOO' || 'BAR');` still returns `TEXT`.

I need it to return VARCHAR because I'm migrating an old Delphi system from Firebird and there are too much code that use `'FOO' || 'BAR'` as a TStringField, but with the TEXT type it needs to be a TMemoField, which is totally different.

---

### Edit¹:

I tried this:

```
with(oConnection.FormatOptions)do
begin
  with MapRules.Add do
  begin
    SizeMax        := 200;
    TypeMask       := 'text';
    TargetDataType := dtWideString;
  end;
end;
```

Tried this too

```
with(oConnection.FormatOptions)do
begin
  with MapRules.Add do
  begin
    SizeMax        := 1;            // Tried with -1 and 0 too
    SizeMax        := 200;
    SourceDataType := dtMemo;
    TargetDataType := dtAnsiString;
  end;
end;
```

But it doesn't work. I think it gets the size set to the value, not the actual size of it. In PostgreSQL the TEXT type do not need any size to be set, so it always get it as a 0 size and convert all TEXT to String doing a big mess that is not pretty.

Comment: What Delphi driver are you using? The dataset mapping might be configurable. In [PgDAC](https://www.devart.com/pgdac/), I think you just need `Connection.DataTypeMap.AddDBTypeRule(pgText, ftWideString, DB.dsMaxStringSize)`.

Comment: @NickBarnes, I'm using FireDAC. I searched about the map rules I can add to it, but could not solve the problem... Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This looks like it: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Data_Type_Mapping_(FireDAC)

Comment: Well, I've been looking to everything in that link but nothing has made the magic...
I will add something in my question about it.

Comment: Judging from the docs, you need a `SourceDataType`, one of these, but I don't know which: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FireDAC.Stan.Intf.TFDDataType

Comment: I've already tried with SouceDataType, the one needing to be converted is the dtMemo to dtAnsiString.... Until now, there is no sign of light for my problem hahaha

Answer (score 3):

The || operator returns type text, so I don't think changing the preferred type will affect anything.  You could define your own operator:

```
-- Before custom operator
select pg_typeof('a'::varchar || 'b'::varchar);
 pg_typeof
-----------
 text
(1 row)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.varcharcat(first varchar, second varchar) RETURNS VARCHAR
  IMMUTABLE
  PARALLEL SAFE
  RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
  LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
    SELECT (first operator(pg_catalog.||) second)::varchar;
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE OPERATOR public.|| (
  FUNCTION = varcharcat,
  LEFTARG = varchar,
  RIGHTARG = varchar
);


select pg_typeof('a'::varchar || 'b'::varchar);
     pg_typeof
-------------------
 character varying
(1 row)

-- Note that text || text still returns text

select pg_typeof('a' || 'b');
 pg_typeof
-----------
 text
(1 row)
```

I will say that I don't think this is a great idea and is likely to have unintended side effects.  It would be much better to get the Delphi system to cast the postgres types appropriately.

Comment: It is something I didn't know was possible hahaha But I'm starting to fear those side effects you said... 
Do you have some idea about a way to make Delphi map the rules correctly?
I'm using FireDAC for everything.

Comment: No, sorry, I've never used Delphi.